# Editing /etc/hosts for MPI cluster

Tags: linux, ip, mpi, cluster-computing, host

I struggled trying to set up an MPI cluster, following [Setting Up an MPICH2 Cluster in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) tutorial. However, I tangled things up and it did not work, so I undid all the changes (except of the passphrase in step 7, which I have no clue how to undo) and I am ready to start a fresh attempt, by asking for guidance.

So, step 1 says to edit /etc/hosts like these (shouldn't that be 'this'?):

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
192.168.133.100 ub0
192.168.133.101 ub1
192.168.133.102 ub2
192.168.133.103 ub3
```

where ub0, ub1, ub2 and ub3 are computers. Last time I did that only for the master node (i.e. ub0). So my question is, should I edit /etc/hosts accordingly to ***all*** nodes, or ***only in the master node***?

Comment: Never setup MPI cluster, but from the knowledge of RHEL cluster setup and a Hadoop cluster setup, I think you need to edit all the node's `/etc/hosts/` file, this is because when the other hosts will refer the `ubX` they won't resolve. Also restart the network so that the updated `/etc/hosts` starts working.

Comment: You are right, but why should I never setup an MPI cluster? I mean, how will I run my MPI program in two computers without doing so? @phoxis

Comment: Possibly setup your configuration using the IP addresses directly?  But I will discourage this process, use names instead, which you can register with a local DNS setup or in the '/etc/hosts`

Comment: @gsamaras I guess when saying "Never setup MPI cluster", phoxis meant "I never setup an MPI cluster before", no need to worry, you are doing it right! Btw, I also never setup an MPI cluster before! :) But a friend of mine was working with it and told me the basic concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do that in all nodes since all nodes need to communicate which each others using their hostname.

Normally a local DNS server would be responsible for address resolution, but this introduces some latency which would slow things down. Using good old `/etc/hosts`, the nodes don't need to make DNS queries since they know each others.

Comment: That's what I thought too, since my 1st attempt went bad, thank you. Nice top answer btw. :)

Comment: @gsamaras Thank you! (Dito) :) .. Good luck with that cluster!